# What's the best practice to use semantic-release to update version number in a node.js or frontend project

Tags: git, continuous-integration, semantic-versioning, gitlab

I'm using [`semantic-release`](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) to auto find out the next version based on the git commit. It's working fine with creating new version, upload to npm and create new git tag. And `semantic-release` is executed whenever code is merged to master.

However, in Node.js or front-end project, usually we have a file named `package.json`. In this file, there is also a version number. My problem is that the version in `package.json` is not updated, which may conflicts with the latest version number on npm. This is said to be done [using `semantic-relase/git` plugin](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/support/faq), however, I'm still confused.

So I wonder what is the best practice?

1. After code is merged to master, run `semantic-release/git` to push a version update commit. However, GitLab stopped me because master is a protected branch and it forbids all direct pushes. I also think that it's not right to direct push.
2. When merged to master, run `semantic-release` to find out next version. Then checkout another branch (maybe called feat_version), update the version and push to feat_version branch, then trigger merge request to master (without approval need). However, this method is a bit complicated and I'm not sure if it can be done in GitLab CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: Protected branches are a GitLab feature, and in no way fundamental to Git.

Comment: Why does the *committed* `package.json` file have to reflect the published version number? Why not follow the policy that only actually published packages (that you retrieve from npm) have a published version number and everything else (even if you were to retrieve the same commit from git) has the version "unofficial local build"?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau what is that policy? Shouldn't the version number in package.json should be consistent with its npm version ? You dont want to pull a package from npm stating version v1.1.0 but in its code package.json still v1.0.0 right ?

Comment: @l0b0 good point, thats why I want to look for a solution that can meet the gitlab protected branches philosophy

Comment: @JakeLam, what I understood from the FAQ of semantic-release, the package that gets uploaded to npm contains a `package.json` file with the correct version number. It is *only* the file in the git repository that doesn't reflect that version number that was derived from the tag.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau oh i just checked and you are right ! the package.json in npm is correct, but its still weird when the version in git repo master is wrong, it may cause confusion for the later maintainer/developer. Even this is just a small one but i was hoping to find a complete solution to solve the inconsistency

Comment: In your git repo version, set it to something like `"version": "0.0.0-semantically-released"` to prevent confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference is for, and experience is with, your first option. Have the CD pipeline filter out "version bump" commits (usually based on the identity of the committing user). Really the second option is only working around the fact that you don't allow the version-bump bot to commit directly to main, and introduces irrelevant branches and PRs.

I find it a little weird when working in this way, that you get a version x.y.z, then a commit with new behaviour but the same version x.y.z, then the commit that bumps the version to (probably) x.y.z+1. The solution for *that* is your option 3 ;), apply the semantic release bump *and* the associated changes as an atomic rebase on top of main.

Comment: thanks for your input, so i guess its ok to do a direct version bump to master

Comment: @jake yes, in my opinion. Master is “protected” in that you don’t want people pushing unreviewed changes, but your version bump script is neither a person nor making a change that goes through code review.